# How to ctrl+click without right clicking?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

A website that I use has different commands for ctrl+click and right click. Because ctrl+click is mapped to right click on Mac, when I use I get the right click action. I want to be able to use the ctrl+click command without it being interpreted as a right click.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Karabiner* (Download-link: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) for this. With *Karabiner* it is possible to reassign every single key.

So you can use the `control`-key for example for letter `i` (meaningless, but useful for your problem).

Lock at the picture below, there I have change the function for `control-right` to write the letter `i`.

[image]

So now I hope you can use `Ctrl` + Click on this website!